# "to stop is important" or "stopping is important"?

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

Do the sentences below sound normal to native speakers?

> 1. To stop him now is important.
>      Stopping him now is important.
> 2. To argue is useless.
>      Arguing is useless.
> 3. To help these people is my duty.
>      Helping these people is my duty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my ear,

1) "To stop him now is important" sounds awkward although I can see it being technically correct.  "Stopping him now is important" (perhaps, to some, emphasises stopping him) is fine, but I would say "It is important to stop him now" (which may emphasise the now part more).

2) Both are fine.  "To argue is useless" to me has a feeling that it is a saying about someone ("To argue with him is useless") or pertaining to bureaucracy: "To argue is useless. To accept inevitable".  "Arguing is useless" is fine, but I would say "It is useless to argue"

3) Similar to 1) - the first sounds awkward, though technically okay.  The second is fine  (perhaps emphasises helping people).  I would say "It is my duty to help these people" (which may emphasise that of course I will help them).